# O que ocorre com a resolução de nome de classes no php 5.5?

Tags: php, classes

O PHP 5.5 implementou uma nova funcionalidade, que consiste em obter o nome da classe através da palavra chave `class`:

Exemplo:

```
namespace testando;
class Teste{}

echo Teste::class; // testando\Teste;
```

Isso funciona corretamente, como esperado.

Agora, eu gostaria de entender por que, quando a classe não existe, obtemos a saída da mesma maneira.

Exemplo:

```
echo ClasseNaoDeclarada::class; //ClasseNaoDeclarada
```

Existe alguma razão especial para obter esse nome (sendo que a classe não foi declarada)?

Comment: O porquê **exatamente** acredito que apenas os envolvido no desenvolvimento do PHP 5.5 (ou que entenda de C) estariam aptos a responder mas, se eu tivesse que adivinhar, eu diria que é por causa do/da Late Static Binding que atrasaria a resolução até o operador :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) assumindo a classe à ele associada.

Comment: Eu não consegui descobrir o motivo, mas quem quiser pesquisar pode olhar a [proposta desse recurso](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_scalars) e o [*pull request*](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/187/files) no repositório.

Comment: Então, pelo que eu entendi, a ideia seria apenas conseguir nomes de classes 'fully qualified' sem esforços e mais elegantemente utilizando aliases ao invés de strings gigantescas com possíveis erros. @bfavaretto boa dica, a proposito

Comment: Eu ando procurando isso e não acho kkkkkkkk um hora a gente acha !!!! kkkkkk

Comment: Vamos ver se agora estimula o tópico ^_^

Comment: De maneira nenhuma classe não declarada pode ser avaliada mesmo se for um atributo externo. Espero ter ajudado

Comment: @Nathan130200: Ajudar, ajudar, não ajudou não (hehe). Toda a discussão é exatamente porque esse *alien* funciona quando deveria lançar um erro justamente por causa da classe não ter sido declarada.

Comment: Essa declaração também não gera um erro quando a classe não existe. Poderia haver algo correlacionado com isso?
`function foo(TTT $a){

}`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Provavelmente sim. Veja a resposta estendida abaixo

Comment: Qual foi o motivo do -1? Poderia mostrar como posso melhorar a pergunta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finalmente uma resposta oficial... em termos. Ela me foi dada por alguém identificado por **requinix@php.net** a partir [deste bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67547) que eu mesmo reportei. Fica apenas a ressalva de que não sei exatamente o quão envolvida com o desenvolvimento da linguagem essa pessoa está.

### TL;DR

> O PHP não precisa da definição de uma classe  para saber o nome completo dela. Tudo que ele precisa ele obtém em tempo de compilação e, por isso, não precisa carregá-la.

### Versão do Diretor

*Namespaces* assim como os *uses* são resolvidos em tempo de compilação, isto é, quando o PHP compila o arquivo **antes** de sua execução. Por esse motivo que existem requerimentos específicos sobre como eles podem ser usados.

Por causa de todos esses requerimentos, quando o PHP encontra o nome de uma classe ele já sabe, de prontidão, o nome completo dela. Imaginando isso como um sistema de arquivos, o *namespace* seria como um diretório para os locais relativos e os *use* seriam links simbólicos (*symlinks*).

O nome da classe pode ser tanto absoluto ("\Testing\Test") ou relativo ("Test") e se for relativo pode ser um nome normal<sup>[carece de contexto]</sup>.

```
namespace Testing {
    echo Test::class; // \Testing + Test = \Testing\Test
}
```

Ou um *alias*:

```
use Testing\Test as AliasedTest;
echo AliasedTest::class; // AliasedTest + use = \Testing\Test
```

Sem tudo isso o *autoloading* de classes não funcionaria!

`::class` é apenas uma nova forma de expor essas informações que o PHP já conhece.

Comment: Show de bola! muito obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Todo o crédito vai para seja ele ou ela quem se deu ao trabalho de proporcionar essa breve explicação através de um veículo impróprio para tanto. Foi realmente surpreendente a boa disposição dele(a) haja vista o pessoal do *bugs* sempre vir coma sapatada pra cima da gente.

Answer (score 3):

Então, a ideia seria apenas conseguir nomes de classes 'fully qualified' sem esforços e mais elegantemente utilizando aliases ao invés de strings gigantescas com possíveis erros.

O nome é dado de acordo com tipo de classe e o namespace e os tipos são `ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_SELF`, `ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_PARENT`, `ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_STATIC`, `ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_DEFAULT`.

No pull request pode-se ver o case: `ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_DEFAULT` que constrói o nome da classe independente da sua 'existencia' ou não. Nos casos de teste o primeiro teste é justamente de uma classe que não existe e nem foi criada em runtime.

Comment: Faz sentido, mas apenas como consideração, essas, ao que me constam, constantes estão presentes **no** *pull request*. Até o momento prevalece o fragmento removido, constante às linhas 2166-2172. O quê exatamente nesse fragmento indica o **motivo** de uma classe não declarada retornar algo ao invés de emitir um **Fatal Error**? Outra coisa... Esse *switch* é baseado numa função que eu imagino ser coisa da própria *engine*. Mas se existe um *switch*, existem condições a cumprir então, esse comportamento seria personalizável?

Comment: Os commits (3, incluindo a resolução de um memory leak) aparentemente foram aceitos sim [por essa mensagem](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/187#issuecomment-12058788) e o código que eu vi do branch PHP-5.5.14 tá lá e o switch foi até melhorado.

O comportamento a cumprir é ele cair nos class types self, parent... e caso não caia, vai pra o default e cola o namespace (se tiver definido) com o nome da classe e pronto

Comment: Em tempo, no branch PHP-5.5 já tem, inclusive